# Django database error: missing table social_auth_usersocialauth when social_auth is not installed

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to deal with a very puzzling error in a Django app. When DEBUG=False, trying to delete a user (via `user.delete()`) gives this database error:

```
DatabaseError: relation "social_auth_usersocialauth" does not exist
LINE 1: ...", "social_auth_usersocialauth"."extra_data" FROM "social_au...
```

However, I do not have social_auth or anything by a similar name in INSTALLED_APPS, nor are there any such tables in my database, nor does any of my code reference anything of the sort (I ran a text search on 'social' in the entire project folder) - and again, this works fine when DEBUG=True. social_auth is installed on my system and on my PYTHONPATH, but I cannot see where this app is getting the idea it should be having social_auth's tables in its database, let alone why it only thinks so when DEBUG=False.

What possible pathways could my app be getting this table from and how could I convince it it's not supposed to be there?

Comment: Can you get a traceback? (Some clue is useful because testing "if settings.DEBUG" is very frequent in Djano source more than 30 times.) Maybe send a traceback by http://dpaste.org/

Comment: http://dpaste.org/ONeeT/

Comment: The code for delete in django.db is not called from django.contrib.admin as I expected but from callback to `tastypie` via your code in `django_projects/kinwins-sever/kinwins/apps/users/api.py`. Then is not possible think about the strange DEBUG behavior if a non Django code is between. On the other side you can easily log the problematic query. I continue in my response due to formating..

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you use the plain Django admin instead of `tastypie`? The same difference between DEBUG True/False? Hmm. It should be easier to turn on logging of errors in Postgresql temporary and look at queries related some last errors. If I would knew in the beginning that you use tastypie instead of normal django I would never try to answer this.

Comment: Yes, the same happens when I try to delete through the Django admin, and again it happens only when DEBUG=False.

Comment: Useful information can be obtained by turning on logging of errors in Postgresql temporary. Can you reproduce the bug on a new user directly after creating? It will be better to log all queries for a short time and compare also succesful queries with debug enabled/disabled if they are the same.

Comment: what version of django are you using? I have the same problem in our envs using 1.3 but not 1.5

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be caused by saved **generic relations** realized by [Django content types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). Relations in Django are not only static, implemented by models and `INSTALLED_APPS` but also dynamic implemented by table `django_content_type` that saves mapping from a numeric id to app_label + model. An example of possible dynamic relationship is a permission or a comment. You can have or have not a permission to any table of any installed application. You can write a comment to everything e.g to an article, to a user to a comment itself without changing any model. This relation is realized by saving numeric id of ContentType related to that model (table) and a primary key of related object (row).

Django does not expect that someone can manipulate the database manually. If you use [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/) for manipulation then if you after uninstalling an application then run `syncdb`, you are asked by south if you want automatically remove orphant content types. Then can be unused tables removed securely without beeing later referenced.

(Possible hack: `delete from django_content_type where app_label='social_auth'` but `south` is unfallible.)

Many parts of the question are still open.

**Edit**:
Why it was not the right way: All generic relations are from descendants to the parent and all data about the relation are saved in descendant. If the child app is removed from INSTALLED_APPS then django.db code can nevermore try to remove descendants because it can not recognize which columns contain the relation data.

Comment: This looked very promising, but I have been using South and ``syncdb`` doesn't detect any orphan content types, and ``SELECT DISTINCT app_label FROM django_content_type`` doesn't get me ``social_auth`` (or anything else that shouldn't be there), yet the error is still happening.

Answer (score -1):

This table is created by `django-social-auth` application.

Looks like you've added it to your project and haven't launched `migrate` (or `syncdb`).

Comment: As I specified in the problem description, though, I don't in fact have it or anything else whose tables might sensibly be prefixed by social_auth in my INSTALLED_APPS, nor is it referenced by any of my code. I have experimented with various third-party apps and I may have briefly tried adding django-social-auth to that project before deciding it wasn't what I was looking for, but if so I uninstalled it long ago and removed all traces of it as far as I can see - I don't see any possible reason it should still be looking for those tables.

Comment: (And to confirm, ``syncdb`` doesn't attempt to create any django-social-auth tables, and ``migrate django-social-auth`` or ``migrate social_auth`` tells me there's no such app.)

Comment: Well, may be some of installed apps requires django-social-auth?