# How to solve facebook django url social-auth-app-django problem?

Tags: django, facebook, url, oauth

Im trying to have social-auth-app-django facebook on my website and im getting this error, on localhost everything works but now when i changed settings to my website it isn't work :(

My settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL='Logowanie'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'MeetMe!'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '***********'  # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '***********'  # App Secret
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/przekierowanie/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'email',
]
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
```

[image: "This domain url isn't included in application settings"]

[image: My domain and subdomains]

[image: My site url]

Comment: First of all, could you please set your Facebook language to English, before you take screenshots of error messages like this. The majority of people here probably doesn’t understand Polish, and you are supposed to present _all_ relevant info in English here.

Comment: If you want to use the server-side login flow, you need to specify your redirect URI in your app settings as well, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#redirecturl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it on my own !

What i did:
added to settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '2.11'
```

i followed this tutorial
[no such table: social_auth_usersocialauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545981/no-such-table-social-auth-usersocialauth)

> 1.pip install python-social-auth==0.2.21
> 2.pip install social-auth-app-django
> 3.Set Django's app list and the backend-related settings according to the settings paragraph of the migration page.
> 4.Apply migrations: python manage.py migrate
> 5.Uninstall the old package: pip uninstall python-social-auth

i set on developers facebook status to live
Domain:
domain.pl

Url:
https://domain.pl

Valid OAuth Redirect URIs:
https://domain.pl/oauth/complete/facebook/

Answer (score 0):

First Go To Setting.py And Put This Code End Of All Codes:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
]
```

Second Go To FaceBook Developer In This Address :
https://developers.facebook.com

And Make One Account There.
After go To My Apps And Then Click On Create App And Then Put Your Website Name ((Attention...If You Use Your Local Host You Need To Put One Domain Name For Your Local Ip)) And Your Email And Click On Create App ID And In Your Dashboard Looking For Facebook Login And Click On Set Up .
And Then In First Step In Web Window Put Your WebSite Name For Local Host For Example Put mysite.com:8000/ And Click On Save And Other Options Just Cross .
Now In Your Dashboard On The Left Side Click On Setting And Then Basic If You See Your APP ID And Your APP SECRET Put This Two In Your Settings.py After That Last Code .

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'Put Your App Id Code Here'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'Put Your App Secret Code Here'
```

If You Want To Take User's Email Also You Can You This As Well .

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
```

Now In You Dashboard Go To Settings And After Go To Basic An In Field App Domains Put Your Website Name Also Go To Settings After Advanced And Put Website Name In Domain Manager With CLick On Add a Domain .

Now Again In Dashboard Go In Products+ Part And Click On Facrbook Login After Settings And Check These Option Be Active(Yes) :

- • Client OAuth Login
- • Web OAuth Login
- • Enforce HTTPS
- • Embedded Browser OAuth Login

And IN This Form Your Are Now Also Go In This Field Valid OAuth Redirect URIs And Put This URL :
exapmle.com/social-auth/complete/facebook/

And Put Your Button In Your Website Page That Have This Login Auth :

```
<li>
     <a href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}">Sign in with Facebook</a>
</li>
```